# How to stop a IIS website by copying a file into it

Tags: asp.net, iis, app-offline.htm

I remember it is possible to stop a website in IIS simply creating a file in the site directory with a special name. But I don't remember the name and can't find it in google. Can you help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

App_Offline.htm, at least for Asp.Net applications.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx

Summary by [Vincent P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598476/vincent-p):

> When you place a file called app_offline.htm in the root of the site, IIS stops the site. Then when you remove the file, IIS starts up and gets going when it receives the first request.

Comment: Links die, so here is a description of what to do: When you place a file called `app_offline.htm` in the root of the site, IIS stops the site. Then when you remove the file, IIS starts up and gets going when it receives the first request.